# How to reproduce the Windows mouse settings on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, mouse, touchpad

Is there a way to import Windows mouse settings to Ubuntu 10.04? I really love Ubuntu but my laptop touchpad is driving me crazy. For e.g. I can not seem to drag the window frame properly. It is not a driver issue, I know this for sure. I think I am accustomed to Windows mouse settings.  Please if you have a setting that works really well can you share it.

Comment: Have you tried installing the Synaptics driver?

Comment: yes I did but nothing works, when I compare windows clicks to that of ubuntu it seems that everything is delayed. I click and then after some milliseconds it actually clicks it.

Answer (score 1):

Mouse settings generally consist of acceleration, speed, and several miscellaneous other things (pointer trail, etc.). To my knowledge, both gnome and KDE, as well as most other GUI interfaces, will let you set both speed and acceleration, at which point it's just trial and error to find something similar to what you're used to in windows.

If you're talking about features such as window dragging, double-clicking the titlebar to maximize, that's dependent on the window manager (Gnome's metacity, KDE's Kwin, Compiz, etc.) and would probably appear under "Window Behavior".

If you're talking about tap-and-drag (which you would use to drag a window) or double-tap-and-drag, those are "gestures" and you might find settings for those under a similarly named configuration section.

TBH it's been a long time since I used linux with a trackpad.

Comment: I fiddled with the settings with no luck for hours. my problem is when I use the mouse it works fine, but the touchpad is no where near what I expected it to be. and I am talking about tap and drag for example when you try to move a windows which is not maximized.